# What version control system should I use for my .Net Express Edition projects?

Tags: c#, version-control, visual-studio-express

I want to start using version control properly for my own personal projects written using Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions.  I'm using both [Visual C# Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) and [Visual Web Developer Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/).

I'm almost always the only developer on these projects.

I've previously used [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) with Windows Explorer integration provided by [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and it worked well, but obviously source control and development were two separate operations.

Is there a better version control system for my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the express edition does not let you use Ankh SVN, which is integrated right into the visual studio interface.  I find Tortoise SVN/Subversion to be easiest with express edition.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the [free, single-user version of SourceGear Vault](http://sourcegear.com/faq.html#singleuser), which works fine as a local repository. Obviously you still need to run the stand-alone client since Express doesn't support add-ins, but it does the job.

Ideally the Express SKUs would [support Codeplex natively](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509150)!

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for a [personal Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing) account and use that.  I've done it and never regretted it.  Reliable SVN hosting for a cheap price.

But no, SVN and Tortoise make a pretty great solution for an individual developer.

Comment: What about trying out a free account to test it out? 3 users, one repository, 100MB space...

Comment: Definitely try out the free account.  I did it until the "one repository" limit came into play...  Without this limit, I might still be on the free version.

Comment: xp-dev is better in that case. 1.5 GB space and private SVN version control. I don't know about no. of users allowed. But I had once given rights to two users. So not less than 3 users. After all it's free. :)

Answer (score 1):

[VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) offers an easy way into SVN, and is free. Mix that with [TortoiseSVN client](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and you're sorted.

Interestingly, TFS2010 [may be interesting](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/10/01/tfs-2010-for-sourcesafe-users.aspx) to single-devs/small-teams, but we'll see how it unfolds.